# Encode/ decode exercise

Tags: python, encode

I am doing a encode/ decode exercise where I have list which is every letter of the alphabet. I prepared a function where I want to shift letters of a word. For example if I chose "hello" and I shift by 1 position I get "ifmmp"

My question comes when I am out of the alphabet. For example If I chose "xyz" and shift by 3 positions I want to get "abc".

alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

I could copy twice the alphabet like below but I would like to do it using only one alphabet.

alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not show your code? Here is a hint: use the mod operator `%`

Comment: Of course, try with an if or the modulo operator. Since it seems an assignment, it depends on the argument of the assignment.

Comment: This is called [Caesar Cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `deque` for this and skip worrying about clamping your indexes. Actually, with this method you don't have to worry about indexes, at all. It's all built-in to `key`. Let's say you wanted to encode "abc". `key` is going to give you `0,1,2`, but when the `deque` has been rotated, the values at `0,1,2` will no longer be "abc". They will be whatever you rotated to.

I reversed the rotation, because you said you wanted to rotate 3 from "xyz" and get "abc". That would require a left rotation, and left rotation in a `deque` is denoted with a negative number. So, we simply negate the rotation, and the numbers you want to use for the direction you want to go match.

```
from collections import deque

key = {k:i for i,k in enumerate(map(chr, range(97,123)))}

def encode(word:str, rotation=0):
    rotkey  = deque(key.keys()) #start fresh every time, so we can destroy past rotations
    rotkey.rotate(-rotation)    #convert rotation to left rotation and rotate
    #encode from the key
    return ''.join(rotkey[key[c]] for c in word)
    

print(encode("hello",5)) #mjqqt
```

**[deque docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)**

---

Per @KellyBundy comments, I provide you with the modulus method. It's less code, but harder to read.

```
key=''.join(map(chr, range(97,123)))

def encode(word:str, rotation=0):
    return ''.join(key[(key.find(c)+rotation)%len(key)] for c in word)
    
print(encode("hello",5)) #mjqqt
```

You could prerotate the keys with slices, which would make it a little easier to read, but then you are back to 2 alphabets.

```
key=''.join(map(chr, range(97,123)))

def encode(word:str, rotation=0):
    k = key[rotation:]+key[:rotation] #pre-rotate
    return ''.join(k[key.find(c)%len(k)] for c in word)
    
print(encode("hello",5))
```

If you are wondering why I made the alphabet with `range` and `map`, it's so you can modify your key simply by changing the range. Which may or may not be useful.

Comment: I don't see how creating the extra deque is any more *"do it using only one alphabet"* than doubling the list is...

Comment: @KellyBundy ~ I thought about that. My opinion is that the simplicity of this outweighs juggling and clamping indexes. Also, this is exactly what deque is for... rotating.

Comment: deque is not just for rotating. Not even primarily.

Comment: @KellyBundy ~ Well, that's great, right? That means there's lots of room for you to make a comparable answer. This is the one I'm going with. There's nothing wrong with it. It does the job, it's easy to understand, and it likely exposes the OP to options they weren't aware of.